# Assign the result of a function to variable?

Tags: haskell

Below code just invokes a function of type :

```
greaterThan100 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

I'm struggling with the simplest of concepts but how to bind/assign the result of this function to a variable ?

```
greaterThan100 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
greaterThan100 [1,9,349,6,907,98,105] = [349,907,105]
```

Cannot use `x = greaterThan100 [1,9,349,6,907,98,105] = [349,907,105]` This syntax does not make sense ?

Comment: Try `let x = greaterThan100 [1,9,349,6,907,98,105]`

Comment: @thefourtheye this works "gt = greaterThan100 [1,9,349,6,907,98,105]" I was double assigning the same value. I'm running this from within .hs file so do not need let statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a .hs file:

```
x = greaterThan100 [1,9,349,6,907,98,105]
```

In GHCi:

```
let x = greaterThan100 [1,9,349,6,907,98,105]
```